# Issue with kali-menu installation in Kali Linux

Tags: installation, kali-linux, package-management

I got the following error message when trying to install kali-menu package in Kali Linux.

```
root@DarkShadow:~# apt-get install kali-menu -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package kali-menu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'kali-menu' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Does this help:  https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/kali-menu   .  I use the Xfce desktop in my Kali system (2019.4) and it seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

kali-menu package is provided in Kali Linux by the kali-rolling repository.

Kali Rolling users are expected to have the following entry in their `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

kali-menu package is also provided in Kali Linux by the kali-dev repository. While kali-dev is publicly accessible to everybody on all Kali mirrors, this distribution should not be used by end-users as it will regularly break.

For more information see [apt sources.list | Kali Linux Documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/).